# Spring data MongoDB match, lookup and projection to select only required field from looked-up document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have below two Document structures. In the structure CRMContact.orgGroupId == OrganizationGroup.id. I would like to fetch all the CRMContact document that matches with sharedGroupIds and also select only a few fields from CRMContact and only OrganizationGroup.groupownername from OrganizationGroup and match/populate **groupId** (with only one field [***groupownername***] populated). I have used below custom implementation but didn't work.

I have included aggregarionsNotWorking which is not working and aggregarions returning entire OrganizationGroup populated. How to achieve this i.e. just to populate groupownername field, using spring data mongodb?

```
@Document(collection = "ww_crm_contact")
public class CRMContact{
    @Id
    protected String id;
    private String displayName;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    private OrganizationGroup groupId; //Ignore //Modified field name orgGroupId

    @Indexed(name = "CRMCONTACT_SHAREDGROUPID_IDX",background = true)
    private List<String> sharedGroupIds = new LinkedList<>();

    @Indexed(name = "CRMCONTACT_ORGGROUPID_IDX",background = true)
    private String orgGroupId;
}

@Document(collection = "ww_organization_groups")
public class OrganizationGroup {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 600049975643062552L;
    @Id
    protected String id;

    private String groupName;
    private int riaId;
    private Boolean isPrivate;

    private String description;
    private Boolean deleted;
    @Transient
    private int count;

    private String groupownerid;
    private String groupownername;
}


@Repository
public class CustomCRMContactDAO {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    public List<CRMContact> getContactsPresentInGroup(List<ObjectId> objectIds){
        LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("ww_organization_groups").localField("orgGroupId").foreignField("_id").as("groupId");
        ProjectionOperation fields = project("firstName","lastName", "primaryId","displayName","groupId.groupownername");

        Aggregation aggregarionsNotWorking = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("sharedGroupIds").in(objectIds)),lookupOperation,unwind("groupId"),fields); //Not Working even if I change the field only to groupownername

        Aggregation aggregarions = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("sharedGroupIds").in(objectIds)),lookupOperation,fields); //


        List<CRMContact> crmContacts =  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregarions, "ww_crm_contact",CRMContact.class).getMappedResults();

        return crmContacts;

    }

}
```